# eps images in latex beamer class

Tags: beamer

I have some troubles with putting eps images into my beamer presentation. I use this code:

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Výsledky a diskuse}
\framesubtitle{Vygenerovaná data}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{50mm}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.36]{korNEJ.eps}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{5mm}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{50mm}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.36]{korNAH.eps}
  \end{minipage}
 \\
  \begin{minipage}[l]{50mm}
   \caption{Graf}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{5mm}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{50mm}
   \caption{\alert{Graf}}
  \end{minipage}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

In those eps images I have also some text, for example word "RANDOM", but after using LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf it shows only "AD" instead of the whole word. If I open that image for example in photoshops it looks like I want it and that word is complete. Also if I put this image into another document with BOOK class, it compiles correctly. Where is the problem?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Can you make the `eps` files available for download and add links to your question? Also, please make you example code complete; the problem could be caused by something elsewhere in the presentation.

Comment: Well why don't you export those eps files with Photoshop to a pdf file for compile them with graphicx without convertions?